# PTIJ Min and Lulav

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In hilchos teshuva 3:7 Rambam defines a Min, or heretic:

> חֲמִשָּׁה הֵן הַנִּקְרָאִים מִינִים. הָאוֹמֵר שֶׁאֵין שָׁם אֱלוֹהַּ
>   וְאֵין לָעוֹלָם מַנְהִיג. וְהָאוֹמֵר שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם מַנְהִיג אֲבָל הֵן
>   שְׁנַיִם אוֹ יוֹתֵר. וְהָאוֹמֵר שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם רִבּוֹן אֶחָד אֲבָל
>   שֶׁהוּא גּוּף וּבַעַל תְּמוּנָה. וְכֵן הָאוֹמֵר שֶׁאֵינוֹ לְבַדּוֹ
>   הָרִאשׁוֹן וְצוּר לַכּל. וְכֵן הָעוֹבֵד כּוֹכָב אוֹ מַזָּל וְזוּלָתוֹ
>   כְּדֵי לִהְיוֹת מֵלִיץ בֵּינוֹ וּבֵין רִבּוֹן הָעוֹלָמִים. כָּל אֶחָד
>   מֵחֲמִשָּׁה אֵלּוּ הוּא מִין:

The mishnah in Sukkah 3:8 states:

> אֵין אוֹגְדִין אֶת הַלּוּלָב אֶלָּא בְמִינוֹ
>
> One may only bind a lulav with his heretic

This raises 2 questions:

1) Why must we bind a lulav with a heretic?

2) What does "his" heretic mean in this context?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80250/759

Comment: The ערבי נחל correctly believe in monotheism, but it's better not to elaborate on the nature of their theological error and foolishness ("וטעותם וטפשותם בדברים אחרים היא שאי אפשר לאומרו בכתב מפני פושעי ורשעי ישראל", *T'shuvos HaRambam* 448).

Comment: Voting to reopen. The duplicate asks about the ד מינים, while this asks about the specific halacha of אגוד.